# Pg-promise stops opening new connections, no error message

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise, node-pg-pool

In my `express-js` app `pg-promise` sometimes stops accepting connections, even for simple things as a `select now()` query. It's very random. I can run a load test and have 100 concurrent requests run for 10 seconds with response times of 100+ req/s. Then suddenly it just stops working and a single curl request won't work even though it does nothing other than making a `select now()` query.

When this happens it sometimes it works by restarting the node app. Sometimes even that doesn't help.

I can always access to express app for routes not accessing the database, so I'm fairly certain this has to do with the database connection.

The connection options to pgp looks like this (details removed):

```
{
    host: '111.111.111.111',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'database-name',
    user: 'database-user',
    password: 'super secret password'
}
```

My simple express route that test the database looks like this:

```
app.get(apiPrefix + '/fail', async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    await db.task(uuid(), async (tx) => {
        const time = await tx.one('select now() as time');

        res.json({status: 'OK', time: time.time});
    });
});
```

I also have a middleware that handles errors and logs them, but nothing is logged when this happens. Sometimes the task event on `pgpFunc.IInitOptions` fires, but never with the "`finish`" prop set to true. The `error` event never fires.

It feels like something is blocking the connection pool, but I can't find out what and why.

Example output from pg-monitor when it fails:

```
14:26:43 connect(***@***); useCount: 0
14:26:43 task(Auth: acb606e2-a79f-42a4-afe7-f94c8e35d2e8)/start
14:26:43 connect(***@***); useCount: 0
14:26:43 task(Auth: eb28be63-dfda-43a2-9884-05415aa54fbe)/start
14:26:43 connect(***@***); useCount: 0
14:26:43 task(Auth: 59ec38c4-be8f-498b-a77b-3a96ecddf41d)/start
14:26:43 connect(***@***); useCount: 0
14:26:43 task(Auth: f024626a-5e59-4675-a3f2-825ed78dd35d)/start
14:26:43 connect(***@***); useCount: 0
14:26:43 task(Auth: df456fad-ed80-4110-995f-0260db4ec118)/start
14:26:43 connect(***@***); useCount: 0
```

Comment: What is your hosting environment? How many connections are allowed? If there is a small limit, if so, then it should be set for the connection pool, with `max` in the connection options. Are you using a direct connection anywhere in your code? If so, you may be leaking connections somewhere.

Comment: Have the same problem both locally on my Mac and on production server running Linux. I always connect thru pg-promise. I haven't set any limit, but I can try to set it to max and see if it helps.

Comment: Is there any way to check number of unfinished connections?

Comment: All connection details, including live and idle connections are within the [connection pool](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool), which you can access via [db.$pool](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#$pool).